# API youtube livestreaming returns emply response

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using API Youtube livestreaming to get videos live on the channel.
The token has already the scope mandatory of the API.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams?part=snippet,cdn,status&mine=true
the channel_id: UCbEMOjxKkHqtJHxzNQgH26w

The channel has already videos live in which visibility is public, when calling the API to get the video live, the response contains items empty.

{
"kind": "youtube#liveStreamListResponse",
"etag": "RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM",
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 0,
"resultsPerPage": 5
},
"items": []
}

Does someone already face the same issue? What should I do to get videos live?
Thank you so much